# 500.0 0x800700c1 on IIS 7.5 ASP 32-bit AppPool on Windows 2008 Server x64

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to get a classic ASP application working in 32-bit mode on our new Windows 2008 Server x64 with IIS 7.5.  I've created an ApplicationPool named 'TEST' that is set to ASP.NET 2.0 in Classic mode and gone into Advanced Settings and set 'Enable 32-Bit Applications' to true for this new AppPool.

I assigned a single web application on our server to this new AppPool and try to load it in the browser.  It gives me a 500.0 error 0x800700c1 which is the error for not a valid Win32 application (re:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/06/09/problems-with-32-bit-asp-net-2-0-dlls-on-a-windows-2003-server-64-bit.aspx)

As soon as I go back into my AppPool and change the enable 32-bit back to false, the particular web application runs fine.  However, there is one piece of the application that will need to run in 32-bit mode which is why I'm trying to get the site to work in 32-bit mode.

I feel like I'm missing something but that 'something' doesn't seem to exist on any websites that tell you the only thing you need to do is enabled 32-bit applications in the AppPool and assign the site to that AppPool.

Comment: Have you tried running a simple classic asp `<% response.write "hello world" %>` page in 32 bit mode?

Comment: perhaps have a dll which is compiled for 64 bit which cannot be loaded in an application pool with 32-bit applications enabled...

Comment: Kev: I have tried that.  I get the same 500.0 error.  I also tried going into my applicationHost.config file and disabling any isapiFilter without a bitness32 precondition...

Comment: ulluoink: I think you may be on to something. The server has ColdFusion 64-bit installed, and perhaps those filters don't have a 64-bit precondition check...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by removing Handler Mapping under the 32-bit application folder that did not have 32-bit modules available.  In this particular instance, ColdFusion 9 64bit was installed on the server and it's Handler Mapping under the folder was causing the 500.0 issue.  I removed the following Handler Mappings:

```
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286671" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286690" path="*.jsp" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286691" path="*.jws" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286692" path="*.cfm" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286693" path="*.cfml" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286694" path="*.cfc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286695" path="*.cfr" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286696" path="*.cfswf" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286697" path="*.hbmxml" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="AboMapperCustom-1207286698" path="*.hbmxml" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\UPSDATA\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```